# How to integrate dart sass @use with a framework like Bulma?

Tags: dart, sass, bulma

I'm trying to use Dart Sass' `@use` to customize Bulma, but as far as I understand it, when I do e.g.

```
@use "utilities/_all" with (
$blue: #0f52ba,
//etc
);
```

I can't then use e.g.

```
@use 'layout/hero';
```

Because the hero sass file expects a global `$colors` which would be redefined here as `_all.$colors`. 
I also tried to load the `utilities/_all` without namespace like this

```
@use 'utilities/_all' as * whith (
//etc
);
```

To no avail… When debugging, I indeed see as set respectively `_all.$colors` and `$colors` but the hero files always throw this error:

```
Error: Undefined variable.
   ╷
14 │   @each $name, $pair in $colors
   │                         ^^^^^^^
   ╵
  layout/hero.sass 14:25  @use
```

Comment: not an answer, but a gh issue to follow on topic: https://github.com/jgthms/bulma/issues/2797